# Grove capacitive fingerprint sensor not working

Tags: sensor, capacitive

I have just purchased one grove capacitive finger print sensor.
[link](https://robu.in/product/grove-capacitive-fingerprint-scanner/).

I am using Arduino Nano and followed there [tutorial](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Capacitive-Fingerprint-Sensor/) but the example code isn’t working.
Blue light on sensor never turn to green as it should according to the code. Also it says register ok without putting any finger on it.

I am sharing the result of full process code.

```
18:12:23.433 -> Uart===> : EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.1.0.8.31.0.1.4.0.F.0.4E.

18:12:23.433 -> 

18:12:23.433 ->

18:12:23.433 -> Usage:

18:12:23.433 -> Please put your finger on the touchpad, from green light which on the touchpad lights on till it lights off.

18:12:23.433 -> Repeat for 4 times.

18:12:23.433 -> If the red light lights on, it indicates that an error occurred.

18:12:23.433 ->

18:12:23.433 ->

18:12:23.433 ->

18:12:23.433 -> Uart<=== : EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.7.0.5.0.0.0.0.C.

18:12:23.480 ->

18:12:23.480 -> Register ok!

18:12:24.456 -> EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.1.0.8.32.0.FF.FF.0.7.2.40.

18:12:24.456 -> Uart===> : EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.1.0.8.32.0.FF.FF.0.7.2.40.

18:12:24.456 ->

18:12:24.456 ->

18:12:24.456 -> Please put your finger on the touchpad, from green light which on the touchpad lights on 
till it lights off.

18:12:24.456 -> To verify your finger print.

18:12:24.456 ->

18:12:24.456 ->

18:12:24.456 ->

18:12:24.502 -> Uart<=== : EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.7.0.8.24.5.0.0.0.0.0.38.

18:12:24.502 ->

18:12:24.502 -> Verify failed,error code = 0x24

18:12:24.502 -> Ret param = 5.0.0.0.0.

18:12:24.502 ->

18:12:24.502 -> Please check the error code through datasheet!

18:12:24.996 -> EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.1.0.3.D.0.11.

18:12:24.996 -> Uart===> : EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.1.0.3.D.0.11.

18:12:24.996 ->

18:12:26.518 -> Uart<=== : EF.1.FF.FF.FF.FF.7.0.3.0.0.A.

18:12:26.518 ->

18:12:26.518 -> Operation succed.

18:12:26.518 -> Delete ok!
```

I get this without doing anything and while light is still blue.

I tried to find datasheet but could not find one to see what this error code mean.
Is it because my module says it is KCT203 and library is for KCT202 ?